# How to get whole line using fgets

Tags: c++, c, string, unix, stdin

I need to read data from DIFFERENT streams (not only from stdin). I have discovered fgets function , it ok to read some restricted number of characters, but I need to get whole string like gets but I have to specify input stream . Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: If you're sure your lines have a maximum size, then use `fgets` with a character array of that size (or perhaps twice the size for good measure). If you don't want any limits at all then you still need to pick a maximum size for the array you use with `fgets` and then use `malloc/realloc` to dynamically allocate and grow a result array that you copy the buffer-fulls you get from the `fgets` calls into.  If the string returned by `fgets` does not contain a newline character then *either* only a partial line was read *or* the last line in the file was read and it didn't contain a newline.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're allowed to use non-standard functions, you could use [getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline).

Comment: @ooga: [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) is a POSIX (2008) standard function (but not a C11 standard function).  It is a good choice if you really do have to worry about lines that are, for sake of argument, longer than 4 KiB.  At least, that's the threshold I use.  For general purpose work, I use `char buffer[4096];` and `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)` and I don't even always ensure that there's a newline in the first 4095 characters — when it doesn't matter (like I'm expecting 32 characters, but need to 'deal' with oddball inputs).

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152451/fgets-not-reading-whole-line

Answer (score 0):

The normal procedure to read a whole file is this:

- Open the file
- Seek to its end
- Read position
- Create buffer of that size
- Seek to beginning
- Read to the buffer
- Close the file

The example on this site does exactly that: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

If you want to read until a special character then just run fgets in a loop where you use realloc to resize your buffer. A common way is to increase the buffer size not by a fixed amount every time, but rather by an increasing value, such as doubling its size every loop iteration. That way you will perform a maximum of log(n) realloc calls.

Comment: While it is fine for small files, this "normal procedure" is not memory efficient for reading gigabyte-sized log files, for which a line-based approach makes more sense. I believe this ought to be mentioned here.

Comment: This answer is to read a "whole file" yet OP's question is 
"get whole line"

Answer (score 0):

Hope I got it... what you need is to look for end of file (EOF), which is set when (guess what?) the end of file is encountered.

As for the buffer size, you can check the stream size first to be sure to allocate enough memory for the receiving buffer.

Using reallocate is usually not a good choice. It is slow and only show that you have not anticipated the memory needs. Unless absolutely necessary (really hard memory constraints), it is better to allocate more than needed than to reallocate. And of course nothing beats a "right" allocation.

Comment: This answer is to "look for end of file (EOF)" yet OP's question is 
"get whole line"

Comment: You're right, I think it still can be of some use. To save on read operations by the hard drive, it's better to read the entire file and then split de file into arrays of pointers on strings. Agreed it have to be a file that fit in todays +4Go computers memory =D